# Is there something like is_empty_but_has_virtual_functions?

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits, is-empty, empty-class

I would like to craft an "interface"/mix-in class (template), and ensure nobody thinks that adding a member to this class template is a good idea, I'd like to `static_assert` on this condition.
Unfortunately, `std::is_empty` does not allow virtual functions (as polymorphic classes need some space to store their virtual function table pointer or equivalent implementation details).

Is there a variant of `std::is_empty` that allows for virtual functions, but not data members (or is it easily written)?

I'd like this to work (plus all dark corner cases I can't think of right now):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};
struct B : A {};
struct AA { virtual ~AA() = default; };
struct BB : AA {};

static_assert(std::is_empty_v<A>);
static_assert(std::is_empty_v<B>);

// These should also work with the replacement for is_empty:
static_assert(std::is_empty_v<AA>);
static_assert(std::is_empty_v<BB>);

int main()
{}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b6b749f07c73b29).

I'm guessing it requires compiler magic or very platform-specific hacks/checks depending on how exactly virtual functions are implemented.

Comment: Can you explain how `std::is_empty<type>::value && std::is_polymorphic<type>::value`  doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: @Peter a class with virtual methods has `is_empty<T>::value == false`

Comment: If you're on a team and you need to enforce coding policies, it might be time to look into a linter: https://github.com/exercism/cpp/issues/8

Comment: You could try exploiting *empty base class optimization*: derive a class from it that has one data member, and check the size of the derived class is the size of that data member.

Comment: @user253751 That doesn't work due to the virtual function table pointer or other implementation defined details that increase the size of a polymorphic class in an implementation-dependent manner.

Comment: @parktomatomi oh don't get me started. Not going to happen anytime soon unfortunately, not at the scale this type of thing would need.

Comment: `I would like to craft an "interface"/mix-in class (template),` can you show examples of such classes? For pure "interface" classes (i.e. only pure virtual functions) a `std::is_polymorphic_v<T> && sizeof(T) == sizeof(dummy_polymorphic)` is enough IMO

Answer (score 3):

I would do this:

```cpp
struct dummy_polymorphic
{
    virtual ~dummy_polymorphic() {}
};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool empty_maybe_polymorphic_v = std::is_empty_v<T> ||
    (std::is_polymorphic_v<T> && sizeof(T) <= sizeof(dummy_polymorphic));
```

It's the best approach I could think of, but it has some limitations:

- We assume that the overhead of a class being polymorphic is always the same (normally a pretty safe assumption, except if your class ends up with several vtable pointers due to multiple inheritance). I don't see any way to get rid
  of this limitation.
- It breaks if `T` has duplicate empty bases:

  ```
  struct A {};
  struct B : A{};
  struct C : A, B {virtual ~C() {}};

  std::cout << sizeof(C) << '\n'; // 16, rather than 8
  ```